# How to add option with value in semantic-ui multiple select?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dropdown, semantic-ui

I can't find the solution for this problem. I want to add new options in semantic-ui multiple select, with values, using javascript, but I can't figure it out how to do it. Exaple:

HTML:

```
<select multiple class="form-control ui fluid search dropdown" name="city" id="city">
    <option value="NY">New York</option>
    <option value="LA">Los Angeles</option>
</select>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#city').dropdown();
```

And let just say that I want to add new option in select list using javascript (for example `<option value="DC">Washington</option>`). How could I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var s = document.getElementById("city");
var option = document.createElement("option");
option.text = "Washington";
option.value= "DC";
s.add(option);
//or add your option at the beginning
s.add(option, s[0];
```

Comment: That doesn't work becouse this is semantic-ui dropdown, and it's options are translated into a <div> elements. I've tried that and it doesn't work.

Comment: This suggestion changes the underlying <select>, so all you need to do afterwards is call  $("#city").dropdown("refresh") to update the semantic-ui dropdown

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer, I put select block in a div with id "cityWrapper", like this:

```
<div id="cityWrapper">
    <select multiple class="form-control ui fluid search dropdown" name="city" id="city">
        <option value="NY">New York</option>
        <option value="LA">Los Angeles</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

and in javascript file, I've inserted options like this:

```
$('#cityWrapper > > .menu').append('<div class="item" data-value="DC">Washington</div>');
```

and that's all.

**EDIT**

You can use `$('#city').dropdown('add optionValue', 'Washington');` in your javascript file, but the value will be the same as text in option (in this case Washington).

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't get any of the above to work instead I just destroyed and re-instantiated the dropdown again:

```
$("#myDiv").dropdown("destroy");
$('#myDiv').dropdown({values: newValuesArray});
//optionally fire the select event to add either the new value(s) 
//or re-add the previously selected values
$("#myDiv").dropdown("set selected", "some value");
```